# can a negative binomial model be used as a sensitivity test for Spatial regression?

Tags: r, regression, spatial, negative-binomial-distribution

I was wondering if someone on here could help

I recently ran a Spatial Durbin Regression model in R which came back with two of my three independent variables had significant beta coefficients. A colleague then advised me that I should run a sensitivity test using a negative binomial model to see if I get the same results. However the results are different as all my beta coefficients become significant.

What I am trying to understand is would this likely be due to the incorporation of the spatially lagged independent variable (which has a significant rho value in the spatial Durbin regression)? And does it make sense to use the negative binomial as a 'sensitivity test' as I would think the assumptions would be different, particularly around spatial autocorrelation.

Comment: Can you say a little more about the initial model?

Comment: Sure, what more information do you require? The initial model dependent variable was counting the number of crimes per region in a  grid. I had three independent variables to test against. I used a Morans I test which confirmed spatial auto-correlation from the spdep package in R which also confirmed spatial autocorrelation in the residuals from an OLS.

Comment: The initial model was for "the number of crimes"? Was it an OLS model, or a count model like Poisson / negative binomial?

Comment: The 'initial' model was a spatial Durbin model, where the dependent variable was the count of crimes per area, This was specified through type= "mixed" from the lagsarlm function from spdep package in R. I created an OLS model as part of building this to test whether there was any spatial autocorrelation in the residuals and support the use of the model. I wanted a model that would take spatial autocorrelation into account. I was then advised to also try the negative binomial to see if it provided similar results to the spatial Durbin model but it one of my coefficients became significant.